# How to start and stop a server child process in node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Long story short, I need to be able to start/stop two child processes inside of a node.js instance. I'm writing tests for my react/express app, and there's one part in the testing where I need to run the api server & the react dev server at the same time, wait for them to fully activate, then perform some operations with them, and then close both of those down and continue with the rest of my testing.

I've looked into `shelljs`, `child_process`, and `concurrently` but I have yet to find a way to elegantly EXIT these processes. I often end up with hanging processes that get left around after the script has terminated completely, or a script that refuses to exit on its own.

For example, here's my (slightly hacky) way of trying to start my server with `child_process`, wait for it to finish starting up before moving on, and then attempting to close it down.

```
import { exec } from 'child_process'

const startNode = async () : Promise<ChildProcess> => {

    /**
     * Starts our backend api
     */

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        const child : ChildProcess | null = exec('npm run start:dev:norestart')

        if(child === null || !child.stdout) return reject(null)

        child.stdout.on('data', data => {

            console.log(data)
            if(data.indexOf('App listening on port') !== -1) {
                resolve(child)
            }

        })

    })

}

const doThing = async () => {

    console.log('Start')
    const child = await startNode()

    child.kill('SIGKILL')
    console.log('Finished')

}

doThing()
```

However, similar to other attempted solutions, my script never exits, and the server never actually stops running (I tested this by opening another terminal at the same time to see if I could run and I got an "error address already in use").

Does anybody know how to run multiple servers as subprocesses in a single node.js instance and close them down properly?

Answer (score -1):

If your server is already running when you start your script, your `Promise` is never resolved and the script just hangs:

```
// what if data value is 'error address already in use'? if condition
// will fails and promise is never resolve
if(data.indexOf('App listening on port') !== -1) {
    resolve(child)
}
```

If the server is not running, your code should work but I'd first make sure that Promise is always resolved before searching for other problems

Comment: If there is a server already running on that port then you would get a "error: port already in use" and the program would exit, not an unresolved promise.

Comment: Note sure I understand your comment - the `startNode` function will not be resolved, and the Express app will exit with a `address already in use` error